# How do I spawn my date picker UI upon first clicking on the date text field?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, modal-dialog, material-ui, focus

I'm using React 16.13.0 and material's KeyboardDatePicker component -- https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker .  I have set it up like so ...

```
import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  KeyboardTimePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
...

          <KeyboardDatePicker
            margin="normal"
            id="date-pickUp"
            label="Select Date"
            format="MM/dd/yyyy"
            value={pickUpDateLabel}
            onChange={(date) => handleDate(date, "pickUp")}
            KeyboardButtonProps={{
              "aria-label": "change date",
            }}
          />
```

The thing I'd like to tweak is that when I click on the text field where you can type in the date or click the icon graphic to bring up the date picker, I would like the date picker UI to come up automatically.  I'm not sure how to configure things though such that as soon as I click on the text field, the UI for the date picker pops up.

**Edit:** I'm unable to get a working app up with the code but here's a screen shot of the text field that is rendered by default with the icon at the right ...

[image]

Right now you have to click on that icon for the date picker to come up, but I would like to be able to click on the text field and immediately have the date picker appear.

**Edit 2:** Screen shot in response to answer given ...

[image]

Comment: Can you create a minimal example and give the link here?

Comment: Not sure why the questions got a down vote. Yes, a working example would be nice and would definitely help speed up a solution, but I really don't think it deserves a down vote. It's an interesting question and I'm voting for it.

Comment: Hi rzwnahmd and @Dekel, having a bit of trouble getting a working app up, but I included a screen shot in my quesiton to illustrate what and where the functionality shoudl occur.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Multiple issues to handle while solving this:

1. Since you want to the focus on the `Input` to control the opening of the DatePicker Popover - has to be a controlled component (which you control the opening of it using a state.
   This state is actually the `open` prop of the `KeyboardDatePicker`
2. Next issue is that once the Popover is closed - the focus is getting back to the `Input`, and once we have a focus the the Popover will open (not good). We can solve this using the `disableRestoreFocus` prop of the Popover.
3. We need to use the `onFocus` of the `Input` to open the Popover, but the `onClose` of the Popover to actually close it (because we control the open-state of the Popover).
4. Lastly - the icon is no longer controlling the opening of the Popover. We need to do this, using the `onFocus` of the `KeyboardButtonProps`.

This is the complete code:

```
const KeyDatePickerContainer = () => {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(null);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <KeyboardDatePicker
      variant="inline"
      value={selectedDate}
      inputVariant="outlined"
      label="With keyboard"
      format="MM/dd/yyyy"
      onChange={newDate => {
        handleDateChange(newDate);
      }}
      KeyboardButtonProps={{
        onFocus: e => {
          setIsOpen(true);
        }
      }}
      PopoverProps={{
        disableRestoreFocus: true,
        onClose: () => {
          setIsOpen(false);
        }
      }}
      InputProps={{
        onFocus: () => {
          setIsOpen(true);
        }
      }}
      open={isOpen}
    />
  );
};
```

Here is a link to a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-pickers-open-modal-click-on-text-kjgjk

Update: if you want to also close the DatePicker once the date was selected you can use the `onChange` function to not only set the new date, but also close the Popover:

```
onChange={newDate => {
    handleDateChange(newDate);
    setIsOpen(false); // Add this
}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  One thing, though -- in your demo and when I integrated this into my application, selecting on a date when the date picker UI comes up doesn't close the UI date picker and populate the underlying text control (I included a screen shot as a second edit to my question).  If that is too hard, before, there used to be "OK" and "Cancel" buttons but those don't appear now.

Comment: Works great!  Will come back and accept tomorrow as SO makes me wait a day before awarding bounty.

Comment: when click on ok after selecting the date it return me to the date of the current day and didn't close the picker.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who uses updated material-ui library (v5), you can use open={bool} attribute to make use of when to open DatePicker.

```
           const [dateOpen,setDateOpen] = useState(false);
           const [dueDate,setDueDate] = useState(new Date());
                <DatePicker
                  clearable={true}
                  open={dateOpen}
                  onClose={() => setDateOpen(false)}
                  label="Due Date"
                  value={dueDate}
                  minDate={new Date()}
                  onChange={(newValue) => {
                    setDueDate(newValue);
                  }}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      onClick={() => setDateOpen(true)}
                    />
                  )}
                />
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else interested I came up with the following solution:

1. You change the `KeyboardDatePicker` to `DatePicker`
2. You take advantage of `InputProps` and add the calendar icon

```
    InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment>
                <Event />
            </InputAdornment>
        )
     }}
```

Working sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/customicon-forked-zitm9?file=/src/DatePicker.js